# Highstock graphic does not reach the end

Tags: javascript, highcharts

This is my JavaScript code:

```
  $.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/from-sql.php?callback=?', function (data) {
        // Add a null value for the end date
        data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);
        // create the chart
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
            xAxis: {

        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
            valueSuffix: ' cm',
            shared: true
        },
        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            floor: 0
        },
        rangeSelector: {
            selected: 1
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        series: [{
            data: data,
            marker: {
                enabled: true,
                radius: 1
            },
            shadow: true,
            tooltip: {
                valueDecimals: 1
            }
        }]
        });
    });
```

My graphic does not reach to the end of the xAxis.Help please.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Yura602/9a76yytu/

Screenshot:[image]

Comment: there is a lot of data but when you select button for range selectors (as 1 ,3m) 3 month's data is displayed so its not incorrect.If you want to set max upto 3 months use setextreme

Comment: You seem to have done this on purpose..? In your code you have a section marked `// Add a null value for the end date` with `data = [].concat(data, [[Date.UTC(2011, 9, 14, 19, 59), null, null, null, null]]);`.